# Angular - after first attempt, console throwing error: "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using [angular-youtube-embed](https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed) package for displaying youtube videos in an ionic app. I have a page where I list all the articles and I have a page for each article. It is working fine when I am trying to play videos when I am on the articles listing page, and when I go to the article page as well, but when I go back to the articles listing page, I can't play the videos anymore and I get the error:

> TypeError: youtubePlayer.playVideo is not a function

This is the controller for the articles listing pages:

```
$scope.playVideo = function(youtubePlayer, index) {
    $scope.videoPlaying[index] = true;
    youtubePlayer.playVideo();
  };

  $scope.$on('$ionicParentView.afterLeave', function(event, data) {
      $scope.videoPlaying = false;
  });
```

Articles listing page html:

```
<div class="iframe" ng-show="article.external_media.length > 0 && article.external_media.url != ''">
            <img ng-hide="videoPlaying[$index]" class="img" ng-src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/{{ article.external_media[0].video_id }}/maxresdefault.jpg">
            <youtube-video ng-show="!videoPlaying[$index]" video-url="article.external_media[0].original_url" player="youtubePlayer" player-vars="playerVars" class="iframe-video"></youtube-video>
            <h1 ng-hide="videoPlaying[$index]">{{ article.title.split(' ', 7).join(' ') }}</h1>
            <div ng-hide="videoPlaying[$index]" class="iframe-overlay" ng-click="playVideo(youtubePlayer, $index)"></div>
            <img ng-hide="videoPlaying[$index]" ng-click="playVideo(youtubePlayer, $index)" class="play" src="icons/play.svg"/>
            <img ng-hide="videoPlaying[$index]" ng-click="playVideo(youtubePlayer, $index)" class="playButton" src="icons/playRectangle.svg"/>
          </div>
```

Comment: Can this help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217543/cant-control-youtube-embed-even-with-document-getelementbyidxyz-playvideo

Comment: I'm not sure what the specific cause of your problem is but I was curious about the code. $scope.videoPlaying appears to be an array and a bunch of directives use it that way but then other code assigns false to $scope.videoPlaying?

Comment: Since I have more articles on that page, I am using $index, and an array in order to hide or show elements on that specific iframe where a user clicks, so that other videos from other articles, don't start playing. When a user clicks somewhere to play a video on a specific article, then image, overlay and some other elements get hidden and youtube-video shows up. That is why I am making it true on click, and false on after leaving the page.